# Finding Correlations between data in dataframe (including binary)

Tags: r

I have a dataset called dolls.csv that I imported using

```
dolls <- read.csv("dolls.csv")
```

This is a snippet of the data

```
Name  Review Year Strong Skinny Weak Fat Normal
Bell  3.5    1990   1      1      0    0    0
Jan   7.2    1997   0      0      1    0    1
Tweet 7.6    1987   1      1      0    0    0
Sall  9.5    2005   0      0      0    1    0
```

I am trying to run some preliminary analysis of this data. The Name is the name of the doll, the review is a rating 1-10, year is year made, and all values after that are binary where they are 1 if they possess a characteristic or 0 if they don't.

I ran

```
summary(dolls)
```

and get the header, means, mins and max's of values.

I am trying to possibly see what the correlations are between characteristics and year or review rating to see if there is some correlation (for example to see if certain dolls have really high ratings yet have unfavorable traits ), not sure how to construct charts or what functions to use in this case? I was considering some ANOVA tail testing for outliers and means of different values but not sure how to compare values like this (In python i'd run a if-then statement but i dont know how to in R).

This is for a personal study I wanted to conduct and improve my R skills.

Thank you!

Comment: The mean of a binary variable tells the proportion of observarion with that characteristic. 
In order to see the relationship between  each characteristic and year, you can group by year and compute the proportion of dolls with each characteristic, that way youll see if there is a trend.

Comment: Hi @Janus, Stack Overflow is generally for more specific programming-related questions. That said, a few good resources for this purpose would be [R For Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/exploratory-data-analysis.html#covariation) or [resources from datacarpentry.org](https://datacarpentry.org/R-genomics/04-dplyr.html). In your code, `summary` returns a `mean` value because it is of numeric type.

Comment: I figured that out so I removed it, I guess Its kinda stupid to do other summary stats, the second part of my question remains. Also thanks for the link @zack

Comment: Put a reproducible pice of your data to do som examples. use `dput` function from  `tidyverse` package.

Comment: @JohanRosa `dput` is actually from base R. There's no need for any packages to use it